# Angular: Use local reference before definition

Tags: javascript, angular, reference, angular-forms

I've got a login form that renders an error message above it, in case the password was wrong. This error message contains a link to a reset password page, which I want to autofill the email-adress.
Therefore, I'm passing the email as url parameter:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()">
  <div class="error" *ngIf="loginError">
    Wrong password.
    <a routerLink="/account/password/forgot" [queryParams]="{email: email.value}">Forgot password</a>
  </div>
  <div class="email-login">
    <input
      id="email"
      #email
      type="email"
      name="Email"
      [ngModel]="emailPreset"
      email
      required>
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem is, that the first compile attemp fails with errormessage "Property 'email' does not exist on type 'LoginFormComponent'.". However, when I save in development mode to initiate a recompilation, it works.

How can I use the reference to #email in [queryParams]?

Comment: What is the text 'email' under the ngModel?   I think that is causing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `$any(email).value`?

Comment: @DevReboot email adds an email validator to the template driven form input

Comment: @AndreiGătej Thank you, I just tried it but I'm getting the same error